# How to implement the navigating action of right click menu in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I am building a demo app, used for handling data. There is a lot of actions available. So I decide to implement a quick menu, which navigate the user to the detail panel, using the right click menu.
I try to use vue-router to mark all function with a unique path, like /action/info, /action/merge. But it turns out to be lack of management.
Are there any good way to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "lack of management"? Can you explain by example?

Comment: @Lana I means that even a small business function should be mark with a unique path. There are too many of them. It seams hard to manage them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue-router makes sense to use if your actions demand a full screen. Otherwise, you can use a simple dialogue. But if you don't want to consider each action as a separate page, I see two options:

**Option 1:** You can use full-screen dialogues: you can show them without changing the route.

**Option 2:** You can use alternative navigation component that navigates without routes. It's not necessary to use it for the whole app. You can use it only for the page where you call all your actions. For example, take a look at [`v-ons-navigator`](https://onsen.io/v2/api/vue/v-ons-navigator.html#main) from Onsen UI. It doesn't use routes, but a stack:

```
// Go to the "main" page by Vue-router and use v-ons-navigator inside to navigate 
// between actions.

<template id="main">
  <v-ons-navigator swipeable
    :page-stack="pageStack"
    @push-page="pageStack.push($event)"
  ></v-ons-navigator>
</template>

<template id="page">
  <v-ons-page>
    <v-ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center">Page</div>
    </v-ons-toolbar>
    <p style="text-align: center">
      This is the page
      <v-ons-button @click="push">Action!</v-ons-button>
    </p>
  </v-ons-page>
</template>

<template id="action">
  <v-ons-page>
    <v-ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left">
        <v-ons-back-button>Page</v-ons-back-button>
      </div>
      <div class="center">Action!</div>
    </v-ons-toolbar>
    <p style="text-align: center">This is the page of the action</p>
  </v-ons-page>
</template>
```

```
const action = {
  key: 'action',
  template: '#action'
};

const page = {
  key: 'page',
  template: '#page',
  methods: {
    push() {

      // Here you go to the page of your action. 
      // You just push it in the stack without changing the route.

      this.$emit('push-page', action);
    }
  }
};

const main = {
  template: '#main',
  data() {
    return {
      pageStack: [page]
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am now considering changing some function to dialog.